android dialog box for picking one video with long filenames
android dialog box for video with long filenames
I want to use a dialog box to pick up a video. But these videos have very long filenames and possibly only differ for the several ending characters.
I try two methods but it depends on the versions how android build-in the dialog box (eg. gallery) and may not display the filenames fully.
Are there more solutions? Best if it can also display the video preview.
1.
intent = createBaseFileIntent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, pickerInitialUri);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, Utils.supportedMimeTypesVideo);
2.
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("/");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/jpeg", "image/png", "video/mp4", "video/quicktime"});

You have no control over how external parties render their UIs, and the result may differ by device model. If you need full control, query the MediaStore and render your own UI.

@CommonsWare do you know how that can be done? Or there exists some reusable code to change a few line of codes?

There has been a fair bit written about MediaStore (albeit not necessarily in Google's docs). For example, I cover it in this chapter of this free older book of mine.
